# Where does the loop break?

Tags: c++, loops, modulo

I'm writing an algorithm to check if a given number is a power of two. I've found a solution online. It does this by continually dividing the number by 2. The solution works, but I don't understand why?

```
i = 32;

 // keep dividing i if it is even
    while (i % 2 == 0) {
      cout << i << " is the current val of i\n";
      cout << i%2 << " is current i mod 2\n*****\n";
      i = i / 2;

// check if n is a power of 2
    if (i == 1) {
      cout << n << " is a power of 2";
```

OUTPUT:

```
32 is the current val of i
0 is current i mod 2
*****
16 is the current val of i
0 is current i mod 2
*****
8 is the current val of i
0 is current i mod 2
*****
4 is the current val of i
0 is current i mod 2
*****
2 is the current val of i
0 is current i mod 2
*****
32 is a power of 2
```

My question: I don't understand why it's not an infinite loop. Where does the loop break? Doesn't `i % 2 == 0` always evaluate to 0?

Comment: If you want to see if an integer is a power of two you could just do `if ((value & (value - 1)) == 0) {}`

Comment: @CaptainObvlious actually you just need [`std::has_single_bit(value)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/bit)

Comment: @phuclv That's a handy function as long as you're using C++20 or greater.

Comment: `Doesn't i % 2 == 0 always evaluate to 0?` No. What's `1 % 2`?

Comment: There it is! How did I miss that? Thank you @Matt

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume the complete program is as follows.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n = 32;
    int i = n;

    // keep dividing i if it is even
    while (i % 2 == 0) {
        cout << i << " is the current val of i\n";
        cout << i % 2 << " is current i mod 2\n*****\n";
        i = i / 2;
    }
    // check if n is a power of 2
    if (i == 1) {
        cout << n << " is a power of 2";
    }
}
```

In the last iteration, `i` becomes 2 so `i == 2/2 == 1` and `i % 2 == 1`, which breaks while loops.